# What am I missing in this relay schedule program?

Tags: python, automation, timer, user-input

I am trying to teach myself Python and am having some questions.  I understand the general idea, I just need some help fine tuning it.
Thank you

```
#imports
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import time

#Relay 1 board number
R1 = 26
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(R1, GPIO.OUT)
h_d = user_input

#start prompts
print("Light schedule")
time.sleep(2)
print("Input hours/day:")                       #Need command to request user input
print("Hours of light per day =", h_d)          #Missing something

#loop
try:
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        GPIO.output(R1,GPIO.LOW)
        if now.hour == 7:                        #Daily start time
            GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.HIGH)
            print("Lights ON @")                 #Need it to print only once per occurrence
            print(time.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))    #Something missing
        elif start_time + user_input
            GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
            print("Lights OFF @")                #Need it to print only once per occurrence
            print(time.strftime("%-I:%M %p"))    #Something missing
    
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What do you want the program to do? What is currently happening when you run it?

Comment: I want the program to ask the user how many hours a day he wants the light on.  Lights on always starts at 7am and goes on for however many hours the user chooses, then it loops every day till stopped.  I need help with asking for user input and other small tweaks, all listed in the notes in the code.

Comment: Python uses [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to get input and [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to change (cast) the string to an integer.

Comment: Also, you don't want your program to run all the time, so in the loop, add a `sleep(60)` to wait one minute between checks.

Comment: `elif start_time + user_input` this line doesn't seem to mean anything, i assume you wanted something like `start_time + user_input > now` however that will be hard to implement. Instead, we can limit ourselves to integer amount of hours and simply check this: `now.hour == (7 + user_input) % 24`